# Set the size of Vaadin GridLayout as the ScreenSize in java

Tags: java, vaadin, fullscreen, screen-size

i'm using `Vaadin` `GridLayout` in a project, and i want to make it big as the screen so i can arrange the UI of the app.

i'm a beginner in java, i tried `.setWidth("100%");` , and also tried 
to get the Screen resolution with `Toolkit`, but it did'nt help.

i've already searched around but none could've helping me.

can anyone give me a hint?

here is a part of it:

```js
  
  filter.setWidth("100%");   //TextField
  entryList.setWidth("100%");   //Table
  entryList.setHeight("100%");
    
  blayout.addComponents(addNew,delete);    //HorizontalLayout
  blayout.setStyleName("buttons");
  Styles style=Page.getCurrent().getStyles();
  style.add(".buttons {float:right;}");
  
    layout1.setMargin(true);    //VerticalLayout
  layout1.setSpacing(true);
  layout1.addComponents(filter,entryList,blayout);
  layout1.setWidth("100%");
  layout1.setHeight("100%");
  layout1.setSizeFull();
    
  layout2.setSizeFull();      //VerticalLayout
  layout2.addComponent(form); // form is a variable of an other class
  layout2.setWidth("100%");
  layout2.setHeight("100%");
  
  MPanel panel1=new MPanel("Search");
  MPanel panel2=new MPanel("Edit");
  panel1.setSizeFull();
  panel2.setSizeFull();
  
  panel1.setContent(layout1);
  panel2.setContent(layout2);
  panel1.setWidth("100%");
  panel1.setHeight("100%");
  panel2.setWidth("100%");
  panel2.setHeight("100%");
  

  mlayout.setRows(1);               //GridLayout
  mlayout.setColumns(2);
  
  mlayout.addComponent(panel1,0,0);
  mlayout.addComponent(panel2,1,0);
  
  mlayout.setSpacing(true);
  

  
  addComponents(new MVerticalLayout(menue, mlayout));   //Creates Output
```

Comment: Could you add the code, that defines the parent components of your GridLayout? Generally you use `setSizeFull()` (shortcut for `setHeight("100%")`, `setWidth("100%")`) which makes the component as large as the available space provided by the parent component.

Comment: did'nt actually worked.  it worked in another app with a HorizontalLayout.